# Unable to crop an image in a for loop using OpenCV on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to crop an image on Android within a for loop in order to calculate the sum of all the pixels in this region:

```
  int patch = 25;


    for (int count1=0; count1<outputMat.cols(); count1 = count1+patch )
    {
       for  (int count2=0; count2<outputMat.rows(); count2 = count2+patch )

            {

              int widthROI = count1+patch-1;
              int heightROI = count2+patch-1;
              Mat ROI = outputMat.submat(count1, count2, widthROI, heightROI);

            }
    }
```

**I get this error:**

`32007-32007/org.opencv.samples.tutorial1 E/cv::error()﹕ OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&), file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp`

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not going out of bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mat.submat` parameters should be in the order:

```
submat(row_start,row_end,column_start,column_end)
```

So the params are in the wrong order.

You are using `.cols()` to calculate width, and using `.rows()` to calculate height.  Change to `count1 < outputMat.rows` and `count2 < outputMat.cols` then use

```
.submat(count1,widthROI,count2,heightROI)
```